# Identificar un objeto desde el botón que apreto

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer que la función detecte qué botón estoy apretando y abrir un modal en función de esto. El script que tengo es:

```js
function openModal(modalName) {
    var modalId = document.getElementById('modal'+ modalName);
    modalId.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
a{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openModal('modal1')">Modal 1</a>
<a onclick="openModal('modal2')">Modal 2</a>


<div id="modal modal1">
  Hola modal 1
</div>

<div id="modal modal2">
  Hola modal 2
</div>
```

PD: Si hago la misma función pero teniendo 1 solo id, por ejemplo: "modal1" la función funciona correctamente, el problema está en alguna sintaxis cuando quiero sumar 2 ids para identificar un elemento.
¿Qué tengo mal acá? Muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora mismo no te funciona porque concatenas "modal"+ "modal1", por lo que estás buscando un elemento con id "modalmodal1"

Comment: No puede haber mas de un id

Answer (score 1):

Veo varias cosas en la respuesta que tu mismo te diste:

1. No deberías tener 2 (o n) elementos con el mismo Id dentro del mismo documento html.
2. Preferir no tener un Id con espacios.
3. Prefiere evitar los handler de eventos en línea (dejo el ejemplo así para no cambiarte la línea de trabajo :P )

Creo que esto te puede funcionar.

```js
function openModal(e) {
    var target = e.target; 
    var modalId = target.getAttribute('data-modal');
    var modalEl = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modalEl.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
a{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openModal(event)" data-modal="modal1">Modal 1</a>
<a onclick="openModal(event)" data-modal="modal2">Modal 2</a>


<div id="modal1">
  Hola modal 1
</div>

<div id="modal2">
  Hola modal 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré es pasar todos los parámetros en el botón. Igualmente me interesaría saber cómo puedo crear una variable con varios Id o Class.

```js
function openModal(modalName) {
    var modalId = document.getElementById(modalName);
    modalId.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
a{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openModal('modal modal1')">Modal 1</a>
<a onclick="openModal('modal modal2')">Modal 2</a>


<div id="modal modal1">
  Hola modal 1
</div>

<div id="modal modal2">
  Hola modal 2
</div>
```